# A bit confused on the derivative order

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives

I am currently watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjlTGUSx-tY&list=PLcrc6i6xwaQT52YtKdIpdARVZ4BTFOrQP&index=6&ab_channel=selcukozyurt) and trying to take the derivative of the following equation:

$(s_i - b_i) F^{n-1} (b^{-1}(b_i))$

The $F$ is a cumulative distribution function and $b(.)$ is just a function. The answer was the following and I don't get where the $\frac{1}{b'(b^{-1}(b_i))}$ part came from.

$(s_i - b_i)(n - 1) F^{n - 2}(b^{-1}(b_i)) f(b^{-1}(b_i)) \frac{1}{b'(b^{-1}(b_i))} - F^{n - 1}(b^{-1}(b_i))$

My thought process goes like this. First, I see that this is in the form of $f(x)g(x)$ so I would have to use chain rule, which means the derivative of what I am looking for is:

$(s_i - b_i) \cdot (F^{n-1} (b^{-1}(b_i))' + (s_i - b_i)' \cdot F^{n-1} (b^{-1}(b_i))$

The $(s_i - b_i)' \cdot F^{n-1} (b^{-1}(b_i))$ part is a bit easier because $(s_i - b_i)'$ is $-1$, so $(s_i - b_i)' \cdot F^{n-1} (b^{-1}(b_i))$ becomes $-F^{n-1} (b^{-1}(b_i))$, cool.

Onto the first part, which is $(s_i - b_i) \cdot (F^{n-1} (b^{-1}(b_i))'$. Following the chain rule, if we do derivative for $(F^{n-1} (b^{-1}(b_i))$:

- We have $\frac{d}{db} [b^n] = nb^{n-1}$, hence the $(n - 1) F^{n - 2}(b^{-1}(b_i))$ part.
- We have the derivative of a CDF is pdf, hence the $f(b^{-1}(b_i)$ part.

However, I am not sure where $\frac{1}{b'(b^{-1}(b_i))}$ came from. Or is it another part of the chain rule, something like $f'(g(u(x))) \cdot g'(u(x)) \cdot u'(x)$? If so, how did $((b^{-1}(b_i))'$ turn into $\frac{1}{b'(b^{-1}(b_i))}$? I couldn't follow the method in the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when you suggest, at the end of your question, that "it is another part of the chain rule." The question then is how to differentiate an inverse function. You might [refresh your memory](https://www.sfu.ca/math-coursenotes/Math%20157%20Course%20Notes/sec_DerivativesofInverse.html) that $\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(x)) = \frac{1}{f^\prime(f^{-1}(x))}$. In the present case, this says that $(b^{-1}(b_i))^\prime = \frac{1}{b^\prime(b^{-1}(b_i))}$ as in the video.